# msmq communication between two public ip

Tags: c#, networking, msmq

I have developed client server model application. I want to send message from server to clients using msmq. message can able to sent via LAN( both are connected in LAN). If both are connected in datacard also message sent. 
But problem is when my server in VM Ware and having public ip , and client is connected with data card, the message is not sent. i have recevied issue like 'failled to connect winsock socket ip=192.75.84.10'

Answer (score 0):

Try next:

1. Ping server machine from client machine (if any errors configure routes)
2. Telnet your server ip and port from client machine and backwards (maybe port is blocked)
3. Check antivirus/firewall on both machines